# How to make my question in high priority on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

Few of my questions are not answered or not viewed by many people which in turn open for long time and if you want move that question up on the question search how can you do that?
The reason is people who might be knowing the solution for my question but not replying as my question is very old.
Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the question ["How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions) for an answer to this.

To summarise your options are;

1. [Offer a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) if you have enough reputation ([you do](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632533/abhisek-bose)).
2. Continue to try to find a solution to your problem, and keep updating your question with your progress.  Questions that have been recently edited will appear first in the ["active"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) section of the [questions tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions).

I think a bounty will be your best bet.